# If B is a N(0,1) R.V., show $E[B^4] = 3$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I've read in Elementary Stochastic Processes by Mikosch (p. 98), that it is a well known fact that:

If B is a N(0,1) R.V., $E[B^4] = 3$

I also see something equivalent (but uncited) on the wikipedia page for moments:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments, namely that:

$E[X^P] = \sigma^P(P-1)!!$ if $P$ is even.

where $ \sigma$ is of course the standard deviation of the R.V./Distn.

Could someone please explain why this is, or link to a proof?

Comment: Hint: For $n$ even, the integral for $E[X^n]$ can be converted to a Gamma function via a change of variables.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918150/

Comment: Taking the 4th derivative of the MGF is quite straightforward. A tad tedious, perhaps, but no special tricks required.